# Leaflet createTile await for image to load

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using the `createTile` with Vue2Leaflet library to make custom tiles. As far as I saw in the documentation, the function runs as many times as there are `coords` on the map. In my case, the function is triggered way more times than I have images to return so at the end I get 90%+ empty tiles that just clutter the map. I was wondering if there is a way to check whether or not an image has a valid path before it returns it? I tried using `image.onload` but it works after the function had already returned
an empty tile.

```
    createTile: function (coords, done) {
      console.log(1);
      var src;
      src = `https://somecoolurl/${coords.x}_${coords.y}_${coords.z}.jpg`;
      const img = window.L.DomUtil.create("img");
      img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      img.src = src;
      img.onerror = function () {
        // handle on error
      };
      img.onload = function () {
        console.log(2);
        // handle if image src was valid
        done(null, img);
      };
      console.log(3);
      return img;
    }
```

In this case, the console will print
`1 3 2`.

If such thing is not possible and `createTile` has to always return a tile, is there a way I can remove tiles from the extended TileLayer once the tiles have been added to it?

Comment: If `createTile` is being called more times than it should, then this looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @IvanSanchez It is being called multiple times because the custom tiles that I want to add belong to multiple TileLayers (e.g have multiple images on different positions that start from 0_0_1). So essentially, I'm looping the creation of tile layers which also loop the `createTile` for all `coords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in my case I was generating multiple TileLayers and I was only specifying the `tileSize` and not the `bounds`. Therefore, the `createTile` was creating unnecessary empty tiles that lowered the performance of the map. It was when I also added `bounds` to each tile layer that the problem was resolved.